# Regular expression filename

Tags: php, regex

I have a site where with jQuery/ajax I want to upload my image.
The problem is when I have strange filename for my image. Like with dots or other.
I have tried with this mode but doesn't work fine, it replace the dot in file extension for example if I have

```
image.test.png
```

become

```
imagetestpng
```

but I want this:

```
imagetest.png
```

This is my code:

```
$name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['upload']['size'];
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $name);
echo($name);
```

How to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Not an answer but some general advice: *do not* use user input (i.e. the filename of the uploaded file) to do any server-side filesystem work. There's a good case for storing uploaded files in the filesystem, but I implore you to use a hash or unique database ID as the filename.

Comment: Also, when you expect to take large numbers of uploads, think of the host filesystem's limitations and performance constraints. You should probably consider applying a subdivision scheme, so that the files are spread across a number of folders. For example, if a given file's unique hash-based filename is "abc123def456.jpg", you could store it under "a/b/c/1/abc123def456.jpg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to decompose the file name:

```
$info = pathinfo($name);
```

Then apply your filter on both parts:

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^\w-]+/", "", $info['filename']);
// check if we have an extension
if (isset($info['extension'])) {
    $name .= '.' . preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '', $info['extension']);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/vCtHGk9G)

Comment: The problem is when I have image with dots inside the name, and seems that this regular expression doesn't solve this problem

Comment: This name is equal, dots is already here I don't understand why "Schermata07-2456482alle14.34.40.png"

Comment: No because there again dots I want to delete dots

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Then what's wrong with the code you already have?!

Comment: This: Schermata07-2456482alle14.34.40.png have to become like this: Schermata07-2456482alle143440.png

Comment: @Jack you got there a lot faster then I did :)

Comment: @Orangepill It was a bit tricky for files that don't have extensions :)

Comment: @Jack I didn't even account for that in my solution...It might be time for me to go to sleep :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to replace the characters in the filename while preserving the file extension.

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/',
                     "",
                     pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME)
        ) . (pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)?"." . pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION):"");
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the period and hyphen? That's not necessary.

Comment: @jack: You're right, but it's better to be safe than sorry. But why write `a-zA-Z`, when `/[a-z]/i` does the same thing?

Comment: @Jack +1 updated... I though for sure you had to escape the hyphen to differentiate it from a range. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: The problem is when I have image with dots inside the name, and seems that this regular expression doesn't solve this problem

Comment: For the input `image.test.png` what do you want the output to be?

Comment: imagetest.png  @Orangepill

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Updated answer should work out for you. Will only perform the replacement on the name portion of the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works fine! I have accpeted the other answer but +1 for the help and the correct answer

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri You accepted the right one, his is much cleaner.